# converting object to string with append method

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, string

On my page I have a section containing UL's and each UL gets populated from an array of strings

```
dealers = [{
    title   : "Brecksville",
    address : "8383 Chippewa Rd.,",
    locale  : "Brecksville, Ohio - 44141",
    phone   : "(440) 740-0535",
    location: {lat: 41.32134300, lng: -81.62338300}
}];
```

For brevity I only show one of the strings in the array of strings...

This string is populated into the UL like so...

```
function populatDealerSummaryList(select, dealers) {
    $listSelector = $("#dealersList"); //The Dealer Summary List

    $.each(dealers, function (i, obj) {
        $listSelector.append(
            "<ul class='dealer-summary-list'>" +
            "<li class='dealerName'>" + obj.title + "</li>" +
            "<li class='dealer-summary-listItem'>" + obj.address + "</li>" +
            "<li class='dealer-summary-listItem'>" + obj.locale + "</li>" +
            "<li class='dealer-summary-listItem'>" + obj.location + "</li>" +
            "<li class='dealer-summary-listItem'>" + obj.phone + "</li>" +
            "</ul>");
    });
}
```

above...the latitude and longitude are represented by obj.location...

the problem is...the lat long only renders as [object, object]

I'm not sure how to pass it correctly to get it to render...please help

Comment: How would you *expect* it to be rendered…? Javascript doesn't know how to turn an object into a string either, other than `[object Object]`. You'll need to do that a little more manually.

Comment: try it in this way "<li class='dealer-summary-listItem'>" + obj.location.lat +"," +obj.location.lng+  "</li>" +

Comment: Here is a JSFiddle...https://jsfiddle.net/tonykiefer/hjwL0v1s/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get this result because `Object` method `toString()` return this output string `"[object Object]"`;

You can write like this:

```
...>" + JSON.stringify(obj.location) + "<...
```

Or

```
...>" + obj.location.lat + ', ' + obj.location.lng + "<...
```

Look at [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/antenko/hjwL0v1s/4/). There are both approaches

Comment: @tony Look at my answer again, I changed it. I added JQuery dependency to your JSFiddle and call `initialize` after document ready event.

Comment: Awesome Antonio...thanks for the help!  I was going cross-eyed trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

```
obj.location is an object that contains two keys inside.
```

You pass in the `<li>` element the entire `object`.

You should just :

```
"<li class='dealer-summary-listItem'>" + obj.location.lat + " " + obj.location.lng + "</li>"
```

Comment: You use `obj.location.lng` twice. One should be `obj.location.lat`

Comment: @DionZac this doesnot work...please see the JSFiddle  https://jsfiddle.net/tonykiefer/hjwL0v1s/